# Sending an embedded image in an email from Classic ASP

Tags: email, asp-classic

I have done this before in ASP.Net; however, not in Classic ASP.

Is it possible (and if so how) to create an HTML email in Classic ASP that includes embedded images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look into [Persits ASPEmail](http://www.aspemail.com).  That package has an [AddEmbeddedImage](http://www.aspemail.com/manual_04.html#4_2) method.

As an alternative, [here is an example using CDOSYS](http://support.jodohost.com/showthread.php?t=7692).

Comment: Awesome.  Was hoping there was a CDOSYS option since we don't have licenses to ASPEmail.  Thanks!